# The number of an uninflected pronoun

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns

Case A:     "There stands the boy who has two heads."
Case B:     "There stand the boys who have two heads." (If you are keeping count, the last two children have a total of four heads.)

My question is, what is the number of each of the *who*s and would linguists consider each of them to be uninflected?

Comment: Can "who" be plural? Would you say: "Who go there?" "Who are on the committee?"

Comment: @PeterShor Why not *The senators who are on the committee ...*?

Comment: Then you use a plural verb because "who" is a referent for the plural word *senators*. You could claim that the real subject of the clause is not *who* but *senators*. But if you ask the question: "Who is on the committee?", the verb is singular even though there are several people on the committee.

Comment: I am clear on whether to use a singular or plural verb.  My question address how a linguist my describe both of the relative pronouns.

Comment: You have to distinguish interrogative _who_ from relative _who_; they have different affordances. _*Who are on the committee?_ is ungrammatical, whereas _the people who are on the committee_ is quite ordinary grammatical English. As for how a linguist might describe the relative pronouns, I'd say they were human animate relative pronouns and subjects in their relative clauses. I wouldn't mention number at all; as you say, it's uninflected. If your program needs a number to chew on, you can copy it from the verb.

Comment: Those who can, do. Those who can't, teach.

Comment: @ John Lawler.  I believe the issue of the interrogative pronoun was raised in the comments, not the question.  You've stated that the two words are uninflected and that you "wouldn't mention number at all."  Yet the two verbs of which we agree are the two subjects have number; I "can copy it from the verb."  What I do not get is the concept that they have no number.  Do either of the following forms of you have number?  You, my friends, are late.  You, my friend, have only one nose.

Comment: @John Lawler I don't think you're saying that "Who are these ..." is wrong. 377 000 000 Google hits. According to Swan, '. . .the grammatical rule would be that when "who" is not followed by a noun that refers to it, the verb is singular. However, when there is a plural noun that serves as the predicate nominative for "who," the verb is plural.' So  "Who is on the committee?" but  "Who are these imbeciles on the committee?"

Comment: I said they have different affordances; I didn't mention "who are these". Basically, what Swan says is you can copy it from the verb. I probly shoulda said "predicate" instead of "verb". My apologies.

Comment: @JohnLawler: [So who are on the waiting list?](http://www.assistiveware.com/support/faq/page/103) — [So who are in the inner circle of world trade?](http://www.converge.org.nz/watchdog/04/06.htm) — The singular is as you say far more common, but I wouldn't call *who are in/on x?* ungrammatical?

Comment: OK, don't then. Clearly they have to be distinguished in any event.

Answer (score 1):

John Lawler wrote in a potentially ephemeral comment:

> You have to distinguish interrogative who from relative who; they have different affordances. **Who are on the committee?* is ungrammatical, whereas *the people who are on the committee* is quite ordinary grammatical English.
>
> As for how a linguist might describe the relative pronouns, I'd say they were human animate relative pronouns and subjects in their relative clauses. I wouldn’t mention number at all; as you say, it's uninflected. If your program needs a number to chew on, you can copy it from the verb.

Answer (score 0):

It's ambiguous. To clarify, you need to say something like "... who in total have two ..." or "... who each have two ...". *Who* does not indicate number. Perhaps some grammarians think otherwise. But, whatever rules there may be on the matter, they are not widely enough known or followed for a writer or speaker to convey a clear meaning relying on them alone.